# Pandas questions: Label Encoder and splitting columns to provide datasets with labels

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am just getting started trying to use pandas and scikit for data analytics. My test set is [NHSTA's open crash dataset](http://on.ny.gov/2uqAKuu) - my goal right now is to do a simple RandomForest classification that predicts the gender of the driver based on other parameters (I'm not focussing on accuracy right now - I want to get things running first)

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


crashes = pd.read_csv("crashes.csv", nrows=100000)


crashes.drop("Case Individual ID", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Case Vehicle ID", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Transported By", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Injury Descriptor", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Injury Location", axis=1, inplace = True)

crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Age'])]
crashes = crashes[crashes.Age >= 10 ]

le = LabelEncoder()
crashes = crashes[crashes.columns[:]].apply(le.fit_transform)
crashes = crashes._get_numeric_data()

crashes_train, crashes_test = train_test_split(crashes, test_size = 0.2)

print "After numeric mapping:",list(crashes_train)

X = crashes_train[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
Y = crashes_train[:,[6]]
print "X=",list (X) #error
print "Y=",list (Y) #error
```

The data columns:

```
After numeric mapping: ['Year', 'Victim Status', 'Role Type', 'Seating Position', 'Ejection', 'License State Code', 'Sex', 'Safety Equipment', 'Injury Severity', 'Age']
```

My questions:

1. I'm trying to split columns 0-5 into the data set and column 6 (Sex) into the label. Why am I getting a `TypeError: unhashable type` when I am trying to print X and Y ?
2. How is it that even after using `LabelEncoder` which translates text values to numerical mappings, when I print "After numeric mapping", it prints the actual labels?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was over thinking - this worked well - simple split on column names
import pandas as pd

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

crashes = pd.read_csv("crashes.csv", nrows=100000)


crashes.drop("Case Individual ID", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Case Vehicle ID", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Transported By", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Injury Descriptor", axis=1, inplace = True)
crashes.drop("Injury Location", axis=1, inplace = True)

crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Age'])]
crashes = crashes[crashes.Age >= 10 ]

le = LabelEncoder()
crashes = crashes[crashes.columns[:]].apply(le.fit_transform)
crashes = crashes._get_numeric_data()

crashes_train, crashes_test = train_test_split(crashes, test_size = 0.2)



print "After numeric mapping:",list(crashes_train)

#X = crashes_train.set_index['Year', 'Victim Status', 'Role Type', 'Seating Position', 'Ejection', 'License State Code']
#Y = crashes_train.set_index['Sex']

Y = crashes_train[['Age', 'Year']]
X  =  crashes_train[['Year', 'Victim Status', 'Role Type', 'Seating Position', 'Ejection', 'License State Code']]
names = crashes_train.columns.values

print "X=",list (X)
print "Y=",list (Y)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X, Y)
print("Features sorted by their score:")
print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rfc.feature_importances_), names), reverse=True))
```